# How to access parameter from previous intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm still fresh to Dialogflow and I've tried my best to search first

What I want to do is something like this:

**This works**

User says: I'm angry to my father!

Intent: angerEmotionCapture

param: father (entity: angryDirectedTo)

agent response: fathers are the worst

**This is my issue**

User says: Thanks for listening

Intent: angerEmotionClosure

agent response: regardless, you need to love your father

My fulfilment is using the inline editor.
On the next response, I want to get param: father

The best googling I can result on I'm supposed to use

`const angerResponse = agent.context.get('angerEmotionCapture-followup').params['angryDirectedTo'];`

However, whenever I add this, my agent response always return null

[Source where I get that agent.context.get().params[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156526/accessing-previous-follow-up-intent-parameters-within-dialogflow-fulfillment)

Comment: I think storing those values in the SQLite database will make it much easier to get the values and follow us. Also, that might be useful for future analysis.

Comment: @DhanukaPerera I am planning to learn SQLite during this side project as well. Can you give me pointer how to use SQLite specifically in Dialogflow? I am familiar with mySQL and understand Android (Java + SQLite) a little

Comment: Don't use SQL for this, Dialogflow offers context which helps you with this. You say you used `context.get()` and that didn't work, have you also added a `context.set()` before that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60485445/6351280

Comment: @Jordi I don't but I set the context via the UI (i.e. input-output context)